# facebook as3 library in flash cs4

Tags: flash, facebook, air, flash-cs4

How can i use facebook as3 library in flash cs4 to build air application. I don't want to use flex here. Cs4 can build air application. But i can not use the library in cs4. Please help me as soon as possible....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the facebook swc to your ide by adding them as an external library path, your just use the source files and add them to your source path
both can be found under

file -> publish settings -> (tab) flash -> (Script: AS3.0) Settings

there you can add to it.

for flash CS3:

To use a SWC file in the Flash authoring environment:

1. Copy the SWC file into the Flash_root/en/First Run/Components directory.
2. Start the Flash authoring environment or reload the Components panel if it was already running. To reload the component list on the Components panel, click the menu button and select Reload.

   The component's icon appears in the Components panel. You can now use the component as if it were any of the built-in components.

source: [livedocs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/1/flex_docs/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=Flex_Documentation&file=00001092.htm)

Comment: its ok to load swc but i didn't succeed to connect facebook. and says facebook is undefined when using new facebook(); Please help me get rid of this...